# Card flip doesn't work on Safari. I think it is because of CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

It works fine on Chrome, Firefox, MS Edge but it does not display properly on safari. Block is supposed to flip 360 degrees and display the image; however, it just become blank in safari, and I am not sure what is the problem. Thank you for reading this post!

This is my react script:

```
<div
              className={
                'aspect-w-1 aspect-h-1 bg-blue-500' + (img0 ? ' flip-card' : '')
              }
              onClick={() => setImg0(true)}
            >
              <img
                src={posts && posts[0].image}
                alt=''
                className={
                  'object-cover object-center max-w-6/4 transition ease-in duration-1000' +
                  (img0 ? ' opacity-100' : ' opacity-0')
                }
              />
            </div>
```

This is my CSS script:

```
@layer utilities {
  .flip-card {
    -ms-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -webkit-transition: transform 2000ms;
    -ms-transition: transform 2000ms;
    -moz-transition: transform 2000ms;
    -o-transition: transform 2000ms;
    transition: transform 2s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and it was not visible on safari because of I didn't add perspective value

```
<div
    className={
      'aspect-w-1 aspect-h-1 bg-blue-500 card transition duration-[2000ms]' +
      (img0 ? ' flip-card' : '')
    }
    onClick={() => setImg0(true)}
  >
    <img
      src={posts && posts[0].thumb}
      alt=''
      className={
        'object-cover object-center max-w-[150%] transition delay-500 duration-1000' +
        (img0 ? ' opacity-100' : ' opacity-0')
      }
    />
</div>
```

```
.animation-delay-2000 {
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }
  .animation-delay-4000 {
    animation-delay: 4s;
  }

  .perspective {
    -webkit-perspective: 1800px;
    perspective: 1800px;
  }

  .card {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  .flip-card {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text inside front and back divs in another div and a p tag.
then in css, for the div put

```
{position: relative;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;}
```

and for the p, put

```
position: relative;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 2px) perspective(2px);
```